# Asking for Programming Languages

Tags: discussion

I want to ask for recommendations for programming languages for a specific need, but the guidelines for asking questions explicitly says not to. My question now is, where would I post such a question to get recommendations? Are there any current SO websites for which this type of question would be relevant or is there some searchable "language database" to find languages with desired properties?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I don't mean: "I want to write X. What would be the best programming language".

More specifically, I have a specific set of requirements (rather than fabricate an example, I will use my own although I'm not asking for the answer here, just where I should properly ask it): 1. The ability to do **very** fast computation, 2. The ability to write and compile it into a GUI application 3. Free or not very expensive. Where would it be appropriate to ask this question?

Comment: I think there's a software recommendation site on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @ckuhn203, Thanks! I found it and am linking to it here for future reference: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. I appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: I guess it depends on what it is. There are sites about servers, dbs, etc... You might check one of those out depending on what you are wanting to accomplish. Though, you will need to read their FAQ's to make sure it is on-topic as I don't know all of their rules

Comment: If that one works for you then it may be helpful to write up a little answer and add the link there

Comment: @Dpiz, It's probably the best shot you have on the exchange network. The worst thing that can happens is they close your question as too broad. (ducks to hide from the stones being thrown)

Comment: @ckuhn203, Thanks. I just asked my question there. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: You may have better luck at [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora). They accept questions like that. A sample with some specific requirements (despite the unspecific title) is *[How do I choose a programming language?](https://www.quora.com/Programming-Languages/I-need-help-choosing-a-programming-language)*. They even accept very broad questions like *[What are the pros and cons and uses of the major programming languages?](https://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-and-uses-of-the-major-programming-languages)*.

Answer (score 7):

[SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to just that. Just please keep their community guidelines in mind when posting a question there.

The following is lifted from their help page:

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features.
> - If you're asking for alternatives, be sure to describe the features you're using and why what you have isn't up for the task.
>
> On the topic of answers, we request that answers demonstrate how the
> recommended product meets the requirement and is suitable for the
> intended purpose.

To @RobertHarvey 's point in the comment below, even given this description, programming language recommendations might still be off topic there. I would encourage anyone reading this to visit their [meta site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/) first to make sure it's on topic.

**I take it back.**

It appears they feel [asking for a programming language recommendation would be too broad](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-programming-language-recommendations-be-allowed-here). It is stated that it *might* be possible to ask for recommendations for libraries and such though. Which, although it does not answer your question, is of interest.

Comment: +1, although the number of possible "which programming language is best for my..." questions is almost unbounded, and they're really not all that interesting as questions.  It's possible they don't allow such questions there.  We don't allow them at all on Programmers.

Comment: Since I found someone asking a similar question on that site, I thought I should link to it: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-programming-language-recommendations-be-allowed-here

Comment: Sounds like there's some debate about it @Dpiz. Thanks for sharing.